# Small HDMI screen loses signal if power is unplugged then plugged back in

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a Small HDMI screen, and it loses signal if power is unplugged from it then plugged back in. i.e. if I unplug its power then of course it loses the signal no surprise there. But if I plug power back in, it doesn't get the signal back.

The brand is "Jun-Saxifragelec", is a 5" screen that was sold as being for raspberry pi, though i'm using it on a  "Mini-PC"/small form factor computer, that runs Windows 10.

The screen is powered by USB. There's no issue with the power. I run into the issue described whether it is plugged into a Wall Plug(with usb socket), or plugged into the computer itself for power.

It connects to the computer with an HDMI cable.

It is the primary and only screen attached to the computer. It does display "AMI"(a BIOS/UEFI make), before loading Windows 10. So it works for the full bootup. (Not like one of those monitors that gets its signal from USB and only works when within Windows/the OS). This one is connected via HDMI so gets its signal via that. And while it has a USB connection too, that's just for power.

Another way to look at it is the screen only works when it is there when the computer starts up. So if I plug it in when it's already in Windows then I get nothing / no signal to the screen.

Any idea the cause?

Comment: No Hot Plug Detection (hpd)? Check pin 19

Comment: Or it could be that without mains power the transceiver chip manages to leech enough power from the HDMI connector to remain partially "on" and ends up in an indeterminate state and the designers weren't smart enough to put reset logic on the power supply side of the screen itself. The result is that the display transceiver basically "hangs" until properly reset by the HDMI being reconnected. It's common for electronics to need extra defensive stuff, particularly regards to power and for that kind of thing to be left out of cheap stuff, especially if they expect everything to happen at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a solution that i've tested and works. This device https://monitordetectkiller.com/

[image]

The main use case described on their website is a bit different to mine, e.g. it talks of an extended display.  But I checked with the guy that runs the site and he said he thought it'd work for my situation, and indeed it did.